# Meteor Blaze renderWithData

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to render a Template via Blaze.
So normally I call

```
Blaze.render(Template.xxx,$("#parentnode")[0]);
```

which works fine.

Now I want to differentiate in the Template xxx who rendered it.
So I want to pass a variable to the Template which I can use to decide who it was.
I tried

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.xxx,{test:"value"},$("#parentnode")[0]);
```

And then tried to access the Data in

```
 Template.xxx.onRendered(function(){console.log(this.test)});
```

which logged "this.test is not defined blabla".
How can I pass data correctly and access it?

Thanks for your answers and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

According to [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) it is not possible to access context object in `onRendered` callback. The `this` keyword refers to the template instance and does not contain any stateful data. What you can do is to render the data properties inside DOM nodes (in hidden elements if you don't want to display them). You can access the DOM from `onRendered` function.

Comment: OTOH you can just access the data context in data functions. You can also set up a data context for the parent template and access that from the child.

Answer (score 0):

Template.currentData() is available when the template is rendered so try using Template.currentData() instead of this and it should work:

```
Template.xxx.rendered = function() {
  var _this = Template.currentData();
  console.log(_this.test)
};
```